# Automatically cycle between web tabs on Android?

Tags: browser

I have an information board in an office which I wish to display live web data from an external source as well as data from an internal source.

I was using [Revolver Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/revolver-tabs/dlknooajieciikpedpldejhhijacnbda?hl=en) for Chrome but this is not supported for Android.

Is there any other way I can achieve that?

Comment: You might want to add information about what device you're using, what Android version and which browser.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you can't find a web browser with this functionality built in, it's something that would be easy to achieve by writing your own web page with a little Javascript to cycle a frame between the pages you want to see; or to add a split-screen with frames.

Answer (score 1):

There is a small web project which does exactly what you are looking for, and it works in any browser (Android included):

https://github.com/stevepeak/taberific